# OkHttp add ETag and If-None-Match

Tags: java, android, okhttp

Use retrofit and okhttp on Android, How to use http cache ETag?
I only add like

```
 File cacheDirectory = new   File(ctx.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath(), "HttpCache");

    OkHttpClient ok = new OkHttpClient();
    try {
        Cache cache = new Cache(cacheDirectory, CACHE_SIZE);
        ok.setCache(cache);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LogUtils.e(LOG_TAG, e);
    }

    ok.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_MILLISEC, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(API_ROOT)
            .setErrorHandler(new APIErrorHandler()).setRequestInterceptor(mRequestInterceptor).setClient(new OkClient(ok));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/5889518) that demonstrates Retrofit + OkHttp. If your server returns an `ETag` header in the response, OkHttp will include `If-None-Match` when validating that header on a conditional GET.

Comment: The server return a `ETag`, but retrofit full log not show ETag header, use curl -I print `ETag

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you have add an your customized intecepter like 
//.addNetworkInterceptor(new CacheInterceptor())
//.addInterceptor(new CacheInterceptor())

that will affect okhttp default eTag operation